# Suppose f is infinitely differentiable on $(-R,R)$ and let $s_n$ denote the nth degree Taylor polynomial centered at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am having some trouble with the following proof.

Suppose f is infinitely differentiable on $(-R,R)$ and let $s_n$ denote the nth degree Taylor polynomial centered at $0$. Fix a point $x\in (0,R)$

How can I show that if  $g$ and $h$ are differentiable functions on $[0,x]$ with $g(0)=h(0)$ and $g'(t) \leq h'(t)$ for all $t \in [0,x]$ then $g(t)\leq h(t)$ for all $t \in [0,x]$

I have been advised to use the mean value theorem which states the following,

if $f(x)$ is defined and continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there is at least one number $c$ in the interval $(a,b)$ . that is $a<c<b$ such that

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

So how can I use this theorem to solve my proof? Really stuck on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the mean value theorem and you call $k(x)=h(x)-g(x)$ you obtain that $$k'(c_y)=\frac{k(y)-k(0)}{y-0}$$ with $c_y \in (0,y),$ for every $y \in [0,x];$ which means $$k(x)-k(0)=k'(c_y)(y-0)=y(h'(c_y)-g'(c_y)) \geq 0$$ for your hypothesis on $h'(x)$ and $g'(x):$ more precisely $h'(t) \geq g'(t) \ \forall t \in [0,x]$ implies $h'(c_y) \geq g'(c_y),$ which means $h'(c_y)-g'(c_y) \geq 0$.

Through this, and the fact that $k(0)=h(0)-g(0)=0,$ you obtain that $k(x)=h(x)-g(x) \geq 0,$ which means $h(x) \geq g(x).$

Comment: If something is not clear, tell me! :)

Comment: thanks for your submission, I will read through it and try and make sense of it all. So it proves that $g(t)\leq h(t)$ for all $t \in [0,x]$?

Comment: It does, I hope. :D

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please leave a green tick :D. Ask for any question :)

Comment: how did you use the mean value theorem in this answer?

Comment: I used it with the function $k:$ the mean value theorem says that $k'(c_y)=\frac{k(y)-k(0)}{y-0},$ which means $k(y)-k(0)=k'(c_y)(y-0).$

Comment: could you edit that into your answer? then I will accept, lastly what is the hyposthesis you mention?

Comment: All done :)! Some more doubts?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a lot of the hypotheses you present. If $f$ is continuous on $[0,b],$ with $f$ differentiable on $(0,b)$ and $f'(x) > 0$ on $(0,b),$ then $f(x) > f(0)$ for $x \in (0,b].$ The proof is just the MVT: For each such $x,$

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c)(x-0)$$

by the MVT. Since $f'(c) >0,$ the above is positive. It follows that $f(x) >f(0).$ We're done.

Comment: thanks for your submission, looking at both answers posted, do they both work?